# How do i print non text data in the same line if inputs have been given like below using end="" in python version 3

Tags: python-3.x

What is the python code to display seven segment numbers horizontally? like below

```
  # ### 
  #   # 
  # ### 
  # #   
  # ###
```

and not like below

```
  #
  #
  #
  #
  #

###
  #
###
#  
###
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your problem is that you are outputting *all* of `one` before starting to output `two`, when you actually want to output them on a line-by-line basis. One way to do that is to split them into lines using `splitlines`, and then `zip` the lines together into a list of tuples which you can print:

```
for (o, t) in zip(one.splitlines(), two.splitlines()):
    print(o, t)
```

Output:

```
  # ###
  #   #
  # ###
  # #  
  # ###
```

For working with an input number, it's probably simpler to split the code out into loops. For example:

```
digits = [
"""
###
# #
# #
# #
###
""",
"""
  #
  #
  #
  #
  #
""",
"""
###
  #
###
#  
###
"""
]
lines = [d.splitlines() for d in digits]
number = 2012
for line in range(len(lines[0])):
    for digit in [int(d) for d in list(str(number))]:
        print(lines[digit][line] + ' ', end = '')
    print()
```

Output

```
### ###   # ### 
  # # #   #   # 
### # #   # ### 
#   # #   # #   
### ###   # ###
```

Comment: @Ramprasadh you are correct about the output. Please see my edit for code to deal with any numeric input (I've only included pictures for numbers 0,1 and 2 but that is easily extended)

Answer (score 0):

```
pattern = ['  # ', '#   ', '# # ', '### ']

numb = [[3, 2, 2, 2, 3], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [3, 0, 3, 1, 3], [3, 0, 3, 0, 3], [2, 2, 3, 0, 0], 
       [3, 1, 3, 0, 3], [3, 1, 3, 2, 3], [3, 0, 0, 0, 0], [3, 2, 3, 2, 3], [3, 2, 3, 0, 3]]

nimp = input('Input number: ')

for i in range (5):
    print('')
    for n in nimp:
        print(pattern[numb[int(n)][i]], end=' ')
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

It's not such a simple task to do, you can try this:

```
print('\n'.join([x + " " + y for x, y in zip(one.split('\n'), two.split('\n'))]))
```